# Autopopulate field in suitecrm

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

I have this ajax call that populate the fields to a related field.

```
YAHOO.util.Event.onDOMReady(function() {
  YAHOO.util.Event.addListener(
    "parent_module_another_module_ida",
    "change",
    ajaxReq
  );

  function ajaxReq() {
    var propertyId = $("#parent_module_another_module_ida").val();

    if (propertyId != "") {
      $.ajax({
        url: "/?entryPoint=ajaxEntryPoint&module=Parent_Module&id=" + propertyId,
        success: function(result) {
          var res = JSON.parse(result);

          $("#price").val(res['price']);

        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

The fields gets auto populated but the format becomes something like 1000.000000 ive tried to modify the precision in its vardefs to 0 but its still the same i want to format the number if possible to something like this 1,000.

Comment: How it is stored in DB? same in precision?

Comment: yes. Ive change all the precision of the fields to 0 and when i save it. The format becomes 1,000 the problem is when i autopopulate it through ajax is there other ways in doing this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use [toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) function of javascript to get the required results.

Following is the modified code:

```
YAHOO.util.Event.onDOMReady(function() {
  YAHOO.util.Event.addListener(
    "parent_module_another_module_ida",
    "change",
    ajaxReq
  );

  function ajaxReq() {
    var propertyId = $("#parent_module_another_module_ida").val();

    if (propertyId != "") {
      $.ajax({
        url: "/?entryPoint=ajaxEntryPoint&module=Parent_Module&id=" + propertyId,
        success: function(result) {
          var res = JSON.parse(result);
            price_val = res['price'].toFixed(0);

          $("#price").val(price_val);

        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```